# React vs CSS animation (transform: translateX)

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, css-transitions, css-animations

I've tryied to implement in React the toggle switch example on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch) https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch .

That's my class:

```
class ToggleSwitch {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { checked: this.props.checked };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <label className="switcher">
        <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.toggle} defaultChecked={this.state.checked} />
      <span className="slider"/>
    </label>,
    document.getElementById("toggleSwitch")
    );
  }
  private toggle() {
    const checked = !this.state.checked;
    this.setState({checked});
    console.log("Checked: " + checked);
  }
}
```

And that's my CSS (same as W3Schools example):

```
.switcher {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 112px;
  height: 72px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switcher input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  transition: .4s;
 border-radius: 36px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  right: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  bottom: 6px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #009ee3;  
}

.input:checked + slider:before {
 transform: translateX(36px);
}
```

Sadly, my toggle button doesn't render any animation while toggle is invoked.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: W3Schools is not related to the W3C in any way, shape or form. Edited your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
I've modified the CSS to have two different classes for the toggle and the TSX to switch the class on click.
Doing that way React see the change and redraw the component.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21179558)

Comment: It's a complete answer to the question... split the CSS class in two different classes, one for the left and one for the right solved the problem. The code is already written on the question, just splitted instead of using transitions. The "major edit" was just an if to choose what class it have to use.